# Access window.parent from embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I already searched google, but I didn't find something useful.

**Goal:**

I need to access `window.parent` from iframe. Let's say that in main window I have just one important variable. I have iframe in this page and in that iframe I want to access to this variable. Best way how to do it is: `window.myVar = 5;` and then in the iframe `window.parent.myVar`.

**Reason:**

Main page has more things to do. In iframe, there is totally different page, where it checks that variable and then it makes some edits. If you know better way how to send JavaScript variable to the iframe than through `window.`, then it will be the best.

**Problem:**

This main page is able to open from filesystem. So, this page URL is like `file:///...` and embedded's URL is classic `http://`, because it requires some PHP processes. This main page is for my users, they can download this html file and run anywhere with internet connection.

**Question:**

But as you many know, you can't access parent's window on different protocols. Is there any way how to override this problem?

Comment: Nope, ports, domains and protocols must match

Comment: You could pass the needed vars via the iframe src. `<iframe src="http://yoursite.com/page.html?myVar=5&anotherVar=whatever">`

Comment: @LilDevil I know, but I mean JavaScript variables. The value I want to send is actually a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think what u are looking for is *[postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)*

Comment: Seems to probably the answer. It is too late now, I will try this tomorrow, anyway thanks for info.

Comment: This helped me to find another way to do it, actually it was pretty simple, I did `var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');`, then `iframe.contentWindow.myVariable = function()...;` and in the iframe window I was able to access `window.myVariable`.